# How to sort by the whitespace character

Tags: shell-script, ls, sort

I have this shell script which lists all the names of subdirectories of the current working directory. Is there any way I can sort the names so that directory with whitespaces in the name comes first and then the other ones?

Here's my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

#search for files in a given directory
for file in $*
do
    ls -1p | tr '/' ' '
done
```

Here's the output it creates :

```
A7 Provided
a7q3.log
a7q4.log
A7 Starters
lsdir1.sh
lsdir.sh
```

Is ther a way I can create an output which would look like

```
A7 Provided
A7 Starters
a7q3.log
a7q4.log
lsdir1.sh
lsdir.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

The sort order is determined by the [`LC_COLLATE` locale setting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Locale#LC_COLLATE:_collation). Most languages set the collation order to something similar than a dictionary: there's a first pass of sorting that's case-insensitive and ignores non-alphanumeric characters such as spaces. Change the collation order to `C`, which sorts strictly by code point so space comes before all printable characters, all Latin uppercase letters come before all other letters, etc.

```
LC_COLLATE=C ls -1
```

or

```
LC_ALL=C.utf8 ls -1
```

---

A lot in your script doesn't make sense (looping over the list of words and expanded patterns from arguments; looping and not using the loop variable in the loop body; calling `ls` in a way that only ever outputs a slash at the end of a line and then replacing that slash by a space). I can't tell you how to fix that because I have no idea what you're trying to do, except I can tell you that `$*` should be `"$@"` because there are very very few cases where any of `$*`, `"$*"` or `$@` makes sense.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `"$*"` makes sense, though not in a loop like that.

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt clear with the description. But your suggestions helped. So, Thank you for that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would like a custom `ls` function that first outputs filenames with spaces in them (if any) and then outputs filenames that don't have spaces? The function below uses bash's `extglob` shell option to enable the wildcard `!(* *)` which means "expand to all of the filenames that don't have a space in them". It also creates a temporary subshell (using parentheses instead of curly braces for the function body) so that your shell's options don't change.

```bsh
function ls() (
  command ls -1 *' '* 2>/dev/null
  shopt -s extglob
  command ls -1 !(* *) 2> /dev/null 
)
```

You don't have to name it `ls`, of course -- name it (almost) anything you like.